# Do citizens of Hong Kong living in Canada - still need a visa to enter Russia for <2 weeks?

Tags: visas, russia, hong-kong-citizens

From what I understand, citizens of Hong kong (i.e. holders or [HK Special Administrative Region passports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Special_Administrative_Region_passport)) do not require a visa to go to Russia for short trips less than 14 days, according to [this page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Chinese_citizens_of_Hong_Kong) Does it make a difference if that person currently lives in another country, such as Canada, citizens of which - do require a visa to go to Russia? The same person is also holding a Canadian passport.

Does current residency play a role in this matter at all, if the person tries to enter Russia as a Hong Kong citizen?

Comment: Russian border guards should not ask about other visas, residences etc - apart from the Russian one. It is in the law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Timatic](http://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=HK&AR=CA&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=RU&EM=CA&TR=00&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C), a Hong Kong citizen does not require a visa to visit Russian for up to 14 days, even if they are a resident of Canada.  Note that you will require an onward ticket in order to be granted entry.

In general, residency does not affect visa requirements, however it's always a good idea to check.

Comment: (+1) Do you mean “affect”? I know several cases where it does affect visa requirements. But in all the examples I know, it would *exempt* you from a visa, not the other way around. Would be curious to know if the converse also exists.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know specifically about Russia but in general it does not make a difference and I would be a little surprised if it did. Being a resident somewhere can *exempt* you from some requirements (e.g. transit in the UK if you have a US green card) but typically not *add* some. Similarly, having Canadian citizenship can help you qualify for some exemptions but not make a visa necessary if you already qualify in another way. Basically, you can show one of your passports to benefit from the most advantageous rules.

What could happen in some cases is that border guards notice you are a Canadian resident (because you come from Canada without a visa - if you are a citizen - or have a long-stay visa or stamps in your passport - if you are not) and question you about that (it's more likely to happen with a country they consider sensitive for some reason, which Canada usually is not).